# How to find the percentage of the number of a certain value in my SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data in MySQL that looks like this. Let's call it "calls" table

| call_no | call_date | caller | call_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 | Mark | 11:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-01 | John | 11:30 |
| 3 | 2022-06-01 | Alice | 1:15 |
| 4 | 2022-06-01 | Mark | 1:30 |
| 5 | 2022-06-01 | Susan | 4:00 |
| 6 | 2022-06-02 | Mark | 9:20 |
| 7 | 2022-06-02 | Alice | 11:15 |
| 8 | 2022-06-02 | Mark | 11:30 |
| 9 | 2022-06-02 | Mark | 2:30 |
| 10 | 2022-06-03 | Alice | 9:00 |
| 11 | 2022-06-03 | Susan | 10:30 |
| 12 | 2022-06-03 | John | 1:00 |
| 13 | 2022-06-03 | Mark | 1:30 |
| 14 | 2022-06-03 | John | 2:30 |

...

I wanted to know the proportion of Mark's calls to the total number of calls every single day on June 1, June 2 and June 3 in terms of percentage.

I am using the following script but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT call_date
     , (SELECT COUNT(call_no) 
        FROM calls 
        WHERE caller='Mark') / COUNT(call_no)*100 AS calls_percentage
FROM calls
GROUP BY call_date
```

There result I am expecting is 40% on June 1st, 75% on June 2 and 20%  on June 3.

Comment: Is it Oracle, MySQL or both? What version of respective DBMS?

Comment: I would appreciate it if the _"click here to see the table"_ is instead posted in a textual form rather than as an image. That way, it reduces the amount of time needed to re-create the scenario. I mean, most people would be interested in doing copy & paste than rewriting everything from image, right?

Comment: Also, _"it doesn't work"_ could mean a lot of thing; like does it return an error? or is the result not as expected? or it's no error, no result?

Comment: I did it but the table structure spoils without HTML

Comment: It's fine, you can just post and try as best as you can to make it look like a table. I'm sure someone will help you edit to make it look like a proper table (that could be me). The point is, posting in textual form will make it easier for others to copy and paste. Whether it look pretty in the question or not, that's secondary.

Comment: See my edit on your question, you can continue to add the rest of the sample data using the same format.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? If you're using MySQL 8 then you have access to window functions. Please also add the results you desire for the given example data, so that it's unambiguous as to what you need (written descriptions are open to interpretation, example results are much more objective).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have caller percentage of all, use this:

```
SELECT 
  c.`caller`,
  COUNT(*) AS totalCalls ,
  COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call_records c1)*100
FROM
  `call_records` c 
GROUP BY c.`caller`
```

Or if you want specific caller just add a where clause; like

```
SELECT 
  c.`caller`,
  COUNT(*) AS totalCalls ,
  COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call_records c1)*100
FROM
  `call_records` c 
  WHERE c.caller='Mark'
GROUP BY c.`caller`
```

EDIT
I saw you want it date wise, try using:

```
SELECT 
  c.`caller`,
  COUNT(*) AS totalCalls ,
  c.call_date,
  (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call_records c1 WHERE c1.call_date=c.call_date)*100) AS callPercentage
FROM
  `call_records` c 
  WHERE c.caller='Mark'
GROUP BY c.`caller` , c.call_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
SELECT call_date, 
SUM(caller = 'Mark') / COUNT(caller) * 100 AS percentage
FROM calls
GROUP BY call_date
```

To add another caller like John, you can do this:

```
SELECT call_date,
SUM(caller = 'Mark') / COUNT(caller) * 100 AS percentageMark,
SUM(caller = 'John') / COUNT(caller) * 100 AS percentageJohn
FROM calls
GROUP BY call_date
```

This will find out the percentage of John's and Mark's calls compared to all calls per day:

```
SELECT call_date,
SUM(caller IN ('Mark','John')) / COUNT(caller) * 100 AS percentageMarkAndJohn
FROM calls
GROUP BY call_date
```

Comment: Thanks! But how about I want to see Mark and John's proportion of calls?

Comment: @PJPAG Add one more output expression, but with `caller = 'John'`.

Comment: I meant what if I want to see the percentage of the combination of the number of calls of Mark and John? I tried SUM(dispo = 'Mark', 'John') / COUNT(no) * 100 but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I edited the answer a last time. The question you asked is answered correctly, so please accept the answer and create a new question if you need further assistance to avoid a never ending story of new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the call_time column is a time data type (with the value at hour position being 00 if not explicitly specified), if you would like to calculate the call duration percentage for Mark each day rather than call count percentage, try this.

```
select call_date,
    concat((select sum(time_to_sec(call_time)) from calls where caller='Mark' and call_date=c.call_date)/sum(time_to_sec(call_time)) * 100,'%') as duration_percentage
from calls c
group by call_date
;
```

Tested it on workbench and got the following result set:
**call_date duration_percentage**
2022-06-01  42.7350%
2022-06-02  67.4699%
2022-06-03  6.1224%